# AWS Fargate takes too long to launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to execute tasks based on ECR container images using Fargate. When I run a task, it stays too long(~30-40 seconds) in `PENDING` state then starts running. What can be the reason for this and how can I configure Fargate properly ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How large is the image?

Comment: @Maurice 96.22 Megabytes

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in the events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS container team member here. 30-40 seconds is what you should be expecting. Consider that when you start a task on Fargate there is a lot that is happening behind the scenes. We are provisioning right-sized infrastructure to run your code, we are connecting it to your VPC and more. Your image isn't too large so that is not the problem. We are working hard to reduce that time but as it stands right now there is not a lot of space to maneuver to go below 30 seconds from launch to `running`. What is your use case? Are you deploying frequently? Are you running your containers as part of a service or running standalone tasks?

Comment: 30-40 seconds is pretty impressive